# What is the reception of flat UI in modern tablet Videogames?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, games, flat-design

Here's what a typical modern iPad game looks like. There's lots of eye candy in this image, like golden gradient borders, buttons that look like gems, gradients, etc. Icons for weapons are drawn in a cartoon-like fashion.

As an independent game developer, I don't have a budget to create this quality of interface or art assets. So my question is - **should I embrace the modern "Flat/Almost Flat UI" in my iPad game?** It will certainly be easier to design code and change. Or is flat UI reserved for websites, and productivity applications?

[image]

Flat UI example:
[image]

Example of flat UI game icons (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugGWX.jpg, credit to Lorc):

[image]

Comment: This matters more whether or not the flat GUI style actually fits with the theme of your game.

Comment: The theme of my game is medieval fantasy RPG.

Answer (score 2):

Look at indie games like 140, Rogue Legacy, Castle Crashers, Limbo. I suggested Rogue Legacy because of the icons you posted. All are great examples. Don't be afraid to create your own unique style.

http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/07/26/rogue-legacy-review

http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/10/16/140-review